Installing GitHub Copilot CLI on WSL
I'm trying to install GitHub Copilot CLI on my Windows laptop, but I'm using WSL on my terminal. When I run this command: npm install -g @githubnext/github-copilot-cli, I encounter issues. I have downloaded Node.js and gh on my machine. I've tried clearing the cache, uninstalling and reinstalling Node.js, and reinstalling the package, but nothing works and I keep seeing the same error repeatedly.
I tried running this command: npm install -g @githubnext/github-copilot-cli,
This is the error I get every time:
npm error code ENOTEMPTY
npm error syscall rename
npm error path /home/reverz1/.nvm/versions/node/v22.5.0/lib/node_modules/@githubnext/github-copilot-cli
npm error dest /home/reverz1/.nvm/versions/node/v22.5.0/lib/node_modules/@githubnext/.github-copilot-cli-RsOsvrUW
npm error errno -39
npm error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/reverz1/.nvm/versions/node/v22.5.0/lib/node_modules/@githubnext/github-copilot-cli' -> '/home/reverz1/.nvm/versions/node/v22.5.0/lib/node_modules/@githubnext/.github-copilot-cli-RsOsvrUW'
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/reverz1/.npm/_logs/2024-07-18T23_57_41_901Z-debug-0.log

and when I run this too :
npm i @githubnext/github-copilot-cli

I get this output, then this command runs forever without giving any other outputs,
here is the output :
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
⠼

